# How can one see homepage in github.com and on Ubuntu?

Tags: web, github

I tried to make a homepage on Ubuntu. Why can't I see my homepage on http://jaakkojseppala.github.io/ although my code is in https://github.com/JaakkoJSeppala/Kotisivu/blob/master/index.html ?

Comment: You didn't follow the proper guidelines needed for hosting a site on GitHub pages. I found this [gist](https://gist.github.com/TylerFisher/6127328) very helpful.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the question does not have anything with Linux

Comment: @K7AAY Its just a dude stuck on setting up a website. But yeah I agree doesn't have anything with Linux.

Answer (score 0):

Did you enabled github pages on the repository and choose a theme?
That are required steps.

Github pages are used to serve static content. Also that question do not have anything with Linux  or Ubuntu in particular.

Other thing you also need to use the name that is your username as name of repository. So you should use jaakkojseppala.github.io as name of the repo and not Kotisivu.
Once you do all those things wait a minute and your pages should be up on the github.

Follow a [getting start guide](https://guides.github.com/features/pages/) for github pages and follow additional links from there if you need more help. Github pages have very good documentation as well on https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pages/

If you want different sites not powered by jekyll on github read some additional pages.